# Правильный путь к файлу на android устройстве

Tags: android

Загружаю файл из сети и записываю его вот таким образом:

```
BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(response.body().byteStream());
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Download/" + messages.get(position).getFile().get(finalI).getName());
```

Затем закрываю соединение и запускаю уведомление о загруженном файле при клике на которое должна открываться папка с загруженным файлом.

```
resultIntent = new Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
resultIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Вот только когда указываем `Uri.parse` и `FileOutputStream` один и тот же путь `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, то открываются (и загружаются) они в разных директориях. При переходе на уведомление открываются "Недавние файлы", а сам файл записался по нужному адресу (на карту памяти, в папку "Download")

Comment: А чем именно не устраивает такое открытие файлов из разных директорий из описания не очень понятно? Можно по конкретнее.

Comment: Я загружаю фото, после чего хочу его сохранить и открыть(открыть папку где оно находится) Я записываю его в Environment.getExternalStorageState+ "/Download/" и пытаюсь открыть Environment.getExternalStorageState() а в итоге это 2 разных пути

Comment: Странно, что вообще что-то открывается, так как `getExternalStorageState` возвращает не путь к папке, а состояние внешнего накопителя - подключен, не подключен, подключен только для чтения и т.п.

Comment: Поправил, вот сейчас всё в таком виде

Comment: Передав URI как `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` вы открываете корень внешней карты памяти, с чего вы взяли, что должна открыться папка Download? Или вам нужно уточнить, что именно вы хотите открыть и в какую папку записать. В этом вопросе я не вижу проблемы, все происходит так, как написано в вашем коде.

Comment: В том и дело что открывается не корень внешней карты. Если в URI добавить к Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() открывается всё равно папка "недавние файлы"

Comment: Нет такой папки "Недавние файлы" - это какая то приблуда того менеджера файлов, которым вы открываете файлы. Сортировка по дате или типа того.

Comment: На разных девайсах свои менеджеры файлов, куда тогда необходимо сохранять файлы? Чтобы вне зависимости от менеджера файлов директория с файлом(куда он был сохранен) открывалась одна и та же?

Answer (score 4):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621077/can-we-open-download-folder-via-intent) похожий вопрос. Используйте

```
startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
```

Comment: Вы забыли сказать, что сначала надо тем же `DownloadManager`'ом файл и скачать

Comment: @woesss, у тс файл качается в папку `Download`, т.е. `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`, туда можно качать хоть `DownloadManager`'ом, хоть руками через стримы

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, стоит пытаться открыть папку таким образом:

```
resultIntent = new Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());    
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/");
resultIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Не помогло, открывает тоже самое что и раньше

Comment: @Heaven Хмм, а если так: `Uri uri = Uri.parse(content:// + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/");`

Comment: @Heaven или так: `Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + messages.get(position).getFile().get(finalI).getName()));`

Comment: В обоих случаях открываются "Недавние"

Comment: @Heaven попробуйте проверить на другом устройстве, может это действительно дело в файл-менеджере

Comment: @Heaven как вариант, можно попробовать заменить `Action` в `resultIntent = new Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT);` на `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` или `Intent.ACTION_PICK`